# Laravel 5 route only works with slash

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, wamp, wampserver

I wrote the following code in the Controllers. The code with the slash is working but the code with the reference is not working.

I get 500 Internal Server Error whenever I am not using a slash

```
Route::get('/', 'WelcomeController@index');

Route::get('welcome', function()
{
    return 'Welcome Page';
});
```

The following is my .htaccess files

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    RewriteEngine On RewriteBase

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes...
    RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

The following is the conf file

```
Alias /pitcher.dev "C:/wamp/www/pitcher.dev/public/" 

<Directory "C:/wamp/www/pitcher.dev/public/">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride all
        Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>
```

I am using windows and wamp server. The mod_rewrite is enabled.

Comment: Run `php artisan route:clear` to make sure your routes aren't cached.

Comment: I tried that but still not working

Comment: Well, what is "not working"? Do you get a 404? Blank screen? 500? Etc...

Comment: When I am using slash then no error otherwise I get a 500 Internal Server Error

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove this line `RewriteEngine On RewriteBase`, AFAIK 500 Internal Server Error occur when your `.htaccess` code is wrong. :D

Try change `Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews` to `Options Indexes FollowSymLinks`.

Comment: I have tried removing `RewriteEngine On RewriteBase` but it didn't work out as well.